# bootstrap carousel Not displaying on my page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, carousel

I am trying to add bootstrap carousel, when I do inspect element, div and the codes are showing but I cant see any Image, buttons or anything at all.

Can somebody please take a look and help me.

The Component of the Carousel is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'  
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import Carousel from 'react-bootstrap/Carousel';
export class BootstrapCarouselDemo extends Component {  
        render() {  
                return (  
                        <div>  
                         <div class='container-fluid' >  
                          <div className="row title" style={{ marginBottom: "20px" }} >  
                          <div class="col-sm-12 btn btn-warning">  
                          How To Use Bootstrap Carousel In ReactJS  
                         </div>  
                         </div>  
                         </div>  
                         <div className='container-fluid' >  
                         <Carousel interval={600} keyboard={false} pauseOnHover={true}>  
                         <Carousel.Item style={{'height':"300px"}}  >  
                         <img style={{'height':"300px"}}  
                         className="d-block w-100"  
                        src={'https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/projects/max_808_webp/83651f42216893.Y3JvcCw5MjAsNzIwLDQzLDI4OA.jpg'}  />  
                           <Carousel.Caption>  
                             <h3>First Demo </h3>  
                                 </Carousel.Caption>  
                                 </Carousel.Item  >  
                                 <Carousel.Item style={{'height':"300px"}}>  
                                 <img style={{'height':"300px"}}  
                                   className="d-block w-100"  
                                    src={'https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/project_modules/fs/29420f102309951.5f552c178f734.png'}    />  
                                       <Carousel.Caption>  
                                   <h3>Second Demo</h3>  
                                      </Carousel.Caption>  
                                         </Carousel.Item>  
                                       <Carousel.Item style={{'height':"300px"}}>  
                                       <img style={{'height':"300px"}}  
                                        className="d-block w-100"  
                                         src={'https://as2.ftcdn.net/v2/jpg/03/62/76/21/1000_F_362762187_IH7I1y3UQfbFx4Rl3voGtIhiWkZIlJvu.jpg'}   />  
                                        <Carousel.Caption>  
                                          <h3>Third Demo</h3>  
                                          </Carousel.Caption>  
                                         </Carousel.Item>  
                                        </Carousel>  
                                </div>  
                        </div>  
                )  
        }  
}  
  
export default BootstrapCarouselDemo
```

The CSS of this is empty.

The page .jsx looks like:

```
import React from "react";
import Footer from '../Components/Footer';
import Navbar from '../Components/Navbar';

import BootstrapCarouselDemo from "../Components/LCLandBanner"

import './Live.css';
const Live = () => {
    return (
        <>

            <Navbar />
            <section>
                <div>
            <BootstrapCarouselDemo></BootstrapCarouselDemo> 
            </div>
            </section>
            <div>
                "hello"
            </div>
            <Footer />
        </>
    )
}

export default Live;
```

Again css is empty.

Page looks like:
[SSofthepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ub2w3.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You Should use the imported component like the below

```
<div className="App">
  <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
  <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
  <BootstrapCarouselDemo />
</div>
```

The [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-07-gxbr8f?file=/src/App.js:116-272) is here you could check it

Comment: Thanks for helping, I can check the sandbox code is working perfectly, but my page is still not showing the carousel, the text " <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
  <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>" is displaying but not the carousel. Do think anything else could be the problem?